# Can't count how many times a word appears in a string

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to solve this problem: Write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s. But I'm struggling with my loop, if the I find the word in the string it adds 1 for every character in the string, think I might have to add a nested loop but don't know which.
That's my code:

```
numOfBobs = 0
for word in s:
    if 'bob' in s:
        numOfBobs += 1
print(numOfBobs)
```

Comment: If you print word, you can see that it is not a word but probably a letter.

Comment: what's your example input?

Comment: `s` should be a list of strings

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "bobtestbobabcbob"
numOfBobs = s.count("bob")
print(numOfBobs)
```

You can use string.count("word") for that

Comment: Can't believe I was trying to do this with `regex` and forgot about `count()`

Comment: Not sure this needs to handle diff. letter cases like - `string = 'bob is going to shop on Bob"s Furniture Store with Bob"s wife'`

Comment: @DanielHao That works as well

Comment: Have you tried it? It won't work.

Comment: @DanielHao strange... the following code worked for me:  s = 'bob is going to shop on Bob"s Furniture Store with Bob"s wife'
numOfBobs = s.count("bob")
print(numOfBobs) if you want it to count "bob" as well as "Bob" you would have to use  numOfBobs = s.count("bob") + s.count("Bob") tho

Answer (score 0):

`for word in s` won't really cut it, because while `word` looks like you mean a "word", Python doesn't know this. It is giving you a character.

```
def countSubstrings(input, search):
    result = 0
    currentIndex = 0
    while currentIndex + len(search) < len(input):
        if input[currentIndex:len(input)] == search:
            result += 1
    return result
```

This is a short draft of how it could look like. Since this is a homework question (assumption, sorry), I'm going to leave it up to you to figure out the off-by-one errors and improvements (hint: `len(x)` is constant in these loops, so maybe pre-compute them).

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
for word in s:
    if 'bob' == word:
        numOfBobs += 1
print(numOfBobs)
```

This will work if your input is list

Comment: In order to explain better (for all user levels), please fix your answer. Instead of writing "This will work if your input is list" show how you revert a string to a list first. This will be more helpful for the community.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).